how to use mpiexec -n 6 file.py in sypder
I am working on Openseespy, I want to do parallel processing in Spyder console
I tried with this approach
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()
ip.run_cell("!mpiexec -n 6 file.py")

but getting the error: file.py is not a valid Win32 application.
